# Windows - Is there any way to monitor filter driver traffic?

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, internals, filter-driver

I'm looking for a way or a tool to monitor the data being send to received by filter drivers via [FltSendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltsendmessage)

I used [DriverMon](https://github.com/zodiacon/DriverMon) to intercept the IOCTLs being send to device drivers, it just doesn't work with mini filters as far as I know.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how this was flagged as offtopic, and the reason being recommendation for book, tool, library or tutorial... This is a very specific technical question.
That said, Windows doesn't provide a general mechanism for hooking this. However, if you want to monitor a specific process communication with a driver, you should be able to intercept the process itself (with a hook), when doing FilterConnectCommunicationPort. Then you have a pipe with the driver, and another with process, and act as intermediary.